# Why Vscode marks ı as U+0131?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had a problem, I solved it but I could not explain the reason of the problem.

My pc and Visual Studio Code is in English. My code is in Turkish.
When I view a code which was written in Turkish (ı) character marks as U+0131. When I run the code it works.

[image]

Comment: Off hand, ı looks a lot like I and l in the font Stack Exchange chooses for me. ğ does not look as much like g.  This kind of typography is interesting... I'm guessing that if someone is used to seeing ı, it doesn't present any ambiguity to them at all, but to someone unfamiliar with the characters, it could be tricky.  That being said, i'd like to see them mark O/0 or I/l/1 with the same concerns.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I found a solution. If I add (ı) to allowed characters, it works and if I untick "unicode highlight Ambiguous Characters Control" it works as well.